# Why PriorityQueue does not order in numeric in Java?

Tags: java

```
PriorityQueue<Pair<String, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(
                 (a,b) -> a.getValue()==b.getValue() ? b.getKey().compareTo(a.getKey()) : a.getValue()-b.getValue()
        );
```

eg. want to sort this {"love":2,"coding":1,"i":2,"leetcode":1} with result as
{"i":2,"love":2,"coding":1,"leetcode":1} but the output result is [love=2, coding=1, i=2, leetcode=1]

Can someone help explain why is it?

Comment: Please post a runnable example. See [ask].

Comment: ... and please properly format  your code.  I recommend you take the StackOverflow  [tour](http://StackOverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to reverse the order of subtracting the values to get descending order.
2. You actually need to remove all the elements to see the order.
3. The Comparator can be written more clearly and succinctly using the `Comparator.comparing` methods.

```
PriorityQueue<Pair<String, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(
    Comparator.comparing((Pair<String, Integer> p)->p.getValue())
      .reversed().thenComparing(Pair::getKey));
while(!pq.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(pq.poll());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this! why when Only numbers are working well to get descending order but does not work when combining with String? like PriorityQueue<Pair<String, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>( (a,b) ->  b.getValue()- a.getValue() );

Comment: @lucyz The order is not guaranteed when iterating over it (check the documentation). Only when removing elements is the order is guaranteed.